# MongoDB - Select where array contains a document field

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

The documents in my `collection("users")` look like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectID(...),
   verifiedFields:
   {
       email: ["user@example.com", "othermail@example.com"],
       phone: [...]
   },
   profiles:
   [
       {
           _id: ObjectID(...),
           fields: 
           {
                email: { value: "user@example.com" }
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

I would like to now select all users who's `profiles.field.email.value` is contained within their `verifiedFields.email`. I would like to avoid having to store a boolean `verified` as the user should be allowed to have multiple profiles with the same fields and this would cause complications later on. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What should be the expected output?

Comment: Simply a set of documents from the users-collection where the email has been verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is:

```
db.users.find({
  $expr: {$gt: [{$size: {$setIntersection: ['$profiles.fields.email.value', '$verifiedFields.email']}}, 0]}
})
```

This query doesn't use indexes, so on performance issue you will need add `verified` field.

Please, check [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) and [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) for better understanding this query. Pipeline used for testing your query was:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { $addFields: {a : '$profiles.fields.email.value'}},
  { $addFields: {b: { $setIntersection: ['$a', '$verifiedFields.email']}}},
  { $match: {$expr: {$gt: [{$size: '$b'}, 0]}}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
collection('users').find({
    'profiles[0].fields.email.value': {$in: 'verifiedFields.email'}
})
```

Comment: `$in` only takes arrays and can't interpret them from strings.